# How can I change the day format from "Monday" to "Mon" with moment.php?

Tags: php, date

https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php/tree/master/src

```
$m = new \Moment\Moment();
echo $m->format('l M d h:i');
```

My output:

```
 Wednesday Nov 08 09:19
```

What I try to achieve:

```
 Wed Nov 08 09:19
```

Comment: The format specifications should mirror this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php/blob/master/src/CustomFormats/MomentJs.php here are all the formats you need for moment.php project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D` is stands for 3 character Day name.

So change your code to :

```
echo $m->format('D M d h:i');
```